# Prevent browser page caching in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I'm developing an application as part of my school project work. Till now everything went fine, until the browser back button showing the previously cached pages even after logout. 
I found below code and thought this would help me.

```
before_filter :set_cache_buster

def set_cache_buster
  response.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate"
  response.headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache"
  response.headers["Expires"] = "Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT"
end
```

I added this code in my application controller. Even after this i'm still able to see cached pages on clicking browser back button.

It would be a great help if some can tell what need to be done to disable browser caching.

Comment: You can disable it from the corresponding environment rb file.  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true, make this line false to disable caching.

Comment: @abhidsm I have already done that. Is there any other way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

After spending some time on Rails cache, I found that `turbolinks` gem is causing the problem for me. So after adding the above code to `application_controller.rb`, I have removed the following....

`gem 'turbolinks'` from `Gemfile`and

`//= require turbolinks` from `application.js`

This solved my problem. Hope it would be helpful for a newbie like me.

Comment: Thanks for posting this solution man. This fixed my issue. Thank god!!